# Why can't I display image from sqlite database to tkinter python?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to display an image from 'sqlite' database to 'GUI tkinter app' but still getting some error,

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=398x568 at 0x18FAC4D01C8>" doesn't `exist`.
```

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
    
conn = sqlite3.connect("base.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
    
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 4""")
record = cursor.fetchall()
    
for row in record:
photo = row[2]
stream = BytesIO(photo)
slika=Image.open(stream).convert("RGBA")
    
root = Tk()
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(slika, root)
label = Label(root, image = slika)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
conn.commit()
```

Comment: `image = slika` should be `image = render`.

Comment: in the Header, do you mean "why can i not display" (mean the not)?